# Trouble with HMVC modular extensions for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I've been developing locally on MacOS X Snow Leopard using PHP 5.3, CodeIgniter 2.0 and HMVC Modular Extensions. Everything has been working great.

Suddenly, for no reason I can pinpoint, I am occasionally getting this error when trying to bring up a page:

> Unable to select the specified
>   database: app Filename:
>   /Library/WebServer/Documents/www/development/appdb/third_party/MX/Loader.php
>   Line Number: 96

The error doesn't occur at any specific place, it just seems to appear every 5-10 page loads or so. It usually goes away after a refresh, although sometimes I may need to refresh a couple of times.

Has anyone encountered this error before? Is it just some flakiness in mySQL on my Mac? (I also tried exporting the current DB and re-importing it under a different name and assigning that new DB, but the problem persists. I don't know of a way to test and "repair" a MySQL DB on a Mac.)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Gary

Comment: Are you sure this is directly related to HMVC? It sounds more like something to do with database sessions. Perhaps try disabling them and see if it goes away, at least to get you closer to the source of the issue.

Comment: hi gray did you find the solution for this question? +1 for same issue... hope you will write something.

Comment: same issue here...because i think my free web host provider restrict database sessions or something related to database they restrict as on my local server site works fine.There is one free host I found with database errors kind of stuff but they put ads....

Answer (score 2):

This is just an issue with your MySQL database. While I'm not sure what that issue is, HMVC has nothing to do with it.

The error comes from there as the loader is extended by HMVC, but no logic is changed. I'd fix up your database or install MAMP.

Comment: Thanks Phil and Wesley. It did turn out to just be a database issue and all is working well now. I appreciate the feedback.