# Codeigntier occasional database connection error

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, connection, hmvc

I'm using Codeigniter, and I have have not had any issues connecting to the database in the past.

I was doing some restructuring of the database (adding columns, inserting data, etc), and now I get an error that only occasionally appears.  It does not appear on any specific page, and usually disappears after refresh.  Only appears every 10-20 times I view a page.

```
A Database Error Occurred
Unable to select the specified database: www.site.com

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 242
```

Seems to be very similar to the problem here:
[Trouble with HMVC modular extensions for CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324467/trouble-with-hmvc-modular-extensions-for-codeigniter)

Looks like it could be a problem with the database itself?  Any suggestions would be appreciated....

Comment: Have you analyzed your tables to see if any of them are in need of repair?

Comment: Analyzed tables returned with "OK" or "Table is already up to date."

Answer (score 0):

Looks like database problem to me, not CI. Maybe your database files are corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

It is a database issue. 
I would suggest you to :

1. Export the db file
2. Take a copy of the project
3. Use a new system and import the db + copy the project folder and see if the problem still remains the same.

Great way to debug the issue.