# CodeIgniter Modular Extensions HMVC database error

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord, model, controller, hmvc

I installed CodeIgniter latest version and Modular extension HMVC [Wiredesignz HMVC Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home).

It is showing annoying error in my server. If I refresh the same page for 100 times 5-10% of total refresh show this error.

```
A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: /Library/WebServer/Documents/modular/third_party/MX/Loader.php

Line Number: 96
```

**Screenshot of the Error**

[image]
Code in Autoload Configuration file `./autoload.php`.

```
$autoload['packages'] = array(APPPATH.'third_party');

$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Code in database configuration file `./database.php`.

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = '*****';
$db['default']['password'] = '*****';
$db['default']['database'] = '*****';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Hope I am clear. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The author of the HMVC for CI is active on the official CodeIgniter forums - I posted this question in the [Modular Extension thread](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/179560/P190/) - maybe that can help you with your problem.

Comment: And the author behind the Modular Extension provided with this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324467/trouble-with-hmvc-modular-extensions-for-codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not HMVC issue, when I change the host it is working perfectly. There might be some database server issue or file permission issue with some hosting or your settings.

Phil, Author of HMVC explained here

[Trouble with HMVC modular extensions for CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324467/trouble-with-hmvc-modular-extensions-for-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting one or both these attributes to `FALSE`:

```
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;

$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

change password of database user
set it simple like mydb.123 
and test
in my case it works